# set dark mode using Laravel Vue3 e Intertiajs

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, tailwind-css, inertiajs, darkmode

I'm using the larastarters kit (https://github.com/LaravelDaily/Larastarters) as a side project to practice with Intertia, Vue and tailwindcss.
I'd like to set dark mode if the user clicks on a button starting with the default media preference.
I use Vuex to read the state from localstorage, everything seems to work, I can successfully set the class dark to the container, but nothing happens, whereas if I bind a single class eg bg-gray-800 the class gets applied.
I'm missing something but I can't figure it out.
Here's the store

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import { getThemeFromLocalStorage, setThemeToLocalStorage } from '../utils/index.js'
// Create a new store instance.
export default createStore({
    state() {
        return {
            darkTheme: getThemeFromLocalStorage(),
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        toggleTheme(state) {
            state.darkTheme = !state.darkTheme;
            setThemeToLocalStorage(state.darkTheme);
        }
    }
});
```

the component:

```
<template>
  <button
    class="rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-purple"
    @click="toggleTheme"
    aria-label="Toggle color mode"
  >
    <template v-if="!dark">
      <svg
        class="w-5 h-5"
        aria-hidden="true"
        fill="currentColor"
        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
      >
        <path
          d="M17.293 13.293A8 8 0 016.707 2.707a8.001 8.001 0 1010.586 10.586z"
        ></path>
      </svg>
    </template>
    <template v-if="dark">
      <svg
        class="w-5 h-5"
        aria-hidden="true"
        fill="currentColor"
        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
      >
        <path
          fill-rule="evenodd"
          d="M10 2a1 1 0 011 1v1a1 1 0 11-2 0V3a1 1 0 011-1zm4 8a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0zm-.464 4.95l.707.707a1 1 0 001.414-1.414l-.707-.707a1 1 0 00-1.414 1.414zm2.12-10.607a1 1 0 010 1.414l-.706.707a1 1 0 11-1.414-1.414l.707-.707a1 1 0 011.414 0zM17 11a1 1 0 100-2h-1a1 1 0 100 2h1zm-7 4a1 1 0 011 1v1a1 1 0 11-2 0v-1a1 1 0 011-1zM5.05 6.464A1 1 0 106.465 5.05l-.708-.707a1 1 0 00-1.414 1.414l.707.707zm1.414 8.486l-.707.707a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414l.707-.707a1 1 0 011.414 1.414zM4 11a1 1 0 100-2H3a1 1 0 000 2h1z"
          clip-rule="evenodd"
        ></path>
      </svg>
    </template>
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    dark: function () {
      return this.$store.state.darkTheme;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    toggleTheme: function () {
      this.$store.commit("toggleTheme");
      console.log(this.$store.state.darkTheme);

      console.log(document.documentElement);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

and the page I want to change color:

```
<template>
  <Head title="Welcome" />
  <div :class="{ dark: isDark }">
    <div
      class="relative flex justify-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100  dark:bg-gray-800 items-top sm:items-center sm:pt-0"
    >
      <div
        v-if="canLogin"
        class="fixed top-0 right-0 hidden px-6 py-4 sm:block"
      >
        <ThemeToggler></ThemeToggler>
        <Link
          v-if="$page.props.auth.user"
          :href="route(routeBasePath + 'dashboard')"
          class="text-sm text-gray-700 underline dark:text-purple-600"
          >Dashboard
        </Link>

        <template v-else>
          <Link :href="route('login')" class="text-sm text-gray-700 underline">
            Log in
          </Link>

          <Link
            v-if="canRegister"
            :href="route('register')"
            class="ml-4 text-sm text-gray-700 underline"
          >
            Register
          </Link>
        </template>
      </div>

      <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="flex justify-center pt-8 sm:justify-start sm:pt-0">
          <svg
            viewBox="0 0 651 192"
            fill="none"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            class="w-auto h-16 text-gray-700 sm:h-20"
          >
            <g clip-path="url(#clip0)" fill="#EF3B2D">
              <path
                d="M248.032 44.676h-16.466v100.23h47.394v-14.748h-30.928V44.676zM337.091 87.202c-2.101-3.341-5.083-5.965-8.949-7.875-3.865-1.909-7.756-2.864-11.669-2.864-5.062 0-9.69.931-13.89 2.792-4.201 1.861-7.804 4.417-10.811 7.661-3.007 3.246-5.347 6.993-7.016 11.239-1.672 4.249-2.506 8.713-2.506 13.389 0 4.774.834 9.26 2.506 13.459 1.669 4.202 4.009 7.925 7.016 11.169 3.007 3.246 6.609 5.799 10.811 7.66 4.199 1.861 8.828 2.792 13.89 2.792 3.913 0 7.804-.955 11.669-2.863 3.866-1.908 6.849-4.533 8.949-7.875v9.021h15.607V78.182h-15.607v9.02zm-1.431 32.503c-.955 2.578-2.291 4.821-4.009 6.73-1.719 1.91-3.795 3.437-6.229 4.582-2.435 1.146-5.133 1.718-8.091 1.718-2.96 0-5.633-.572-8.019-1.718-2.387-1.146-4.438-2.672-6.156-4.582-1.719-1.909-3.032-4.152-3.938-6.73-.909-2.577-1.36-5.298-1.36-8.161 0-2.864.451-5.585 1.36-8.162.905-2.577 2.219-4.819 3.938-6.729 1.718-1.908 3.77-3.437 6.156-4.582 2.386-1.146 5.059-1.718 8.019-1.718 2.958 0 5.656.572 8.091 1.718 2.434 1.146 4.51 2.674 6.229 4.582 1.718 1.91 3.054 4.152 4.009 6.729.953 2.577 1.432 5.298 1.432 8.162-.001 2.863-.479 5.584-1.432 8.161zM463.954 87.202c-2.101-3.341-5.083-5.965-8.949-7.875-3.865-1.909-7.756-2.864-11.669-2.864-5.062 0-9.69.931-13.89 2.792-4.201 1.861-7.804 4.417-10.811 7.661-3.007 3.246-5.347 6.993-7.016 11.239-1.672 4.249-2.506 8.713-2.506 13.389 0 4.774.834 9.26 2.506 13.459 1.669 4.202 4.009 7.925 7.016 11.169 3.007 3.246 6.609 5.799 10.811 7.66 4.199 1.861 8.828 2.792 13.89 2.792 3.913 0 7.804-.955 11.669-2.863 3.866-1.908 6.849-4.533 8.949-7.875v9.021h15.607V78.182h-15.607v9.02zm-1.432 32.503c-.955 2.578-2.291 4.821-4.009 6.73-1.719 1.91-3.795 3.437-6.229 4.582-2.435 1.146-5.133 1.718-8.091 1.718-2.96 0-5.633-.572-8.019-1.718-2.387-1.146-4.438-2.672-6.156-4.582-1.719-1.909-3.032-4.152-3.938-6.73-.909-2.577-1.36-5.298-1.36-8.161 0-2.864.451-5.585 1.36-8.162.905-2.577 2.219-4.819 3.938-6.729 1.718-1.908 3.77-3.437 6.156-4.582 2.386-1.146 5.059-1.718 8.019-1.718 2.958 0 5.656.572 8.091 1.718 2.434 1.146 4.51 2.674 6.229 4.582 1.718 1.91 3.054 4.152 4.009 6.729.953 2.577 1.432 5.298 1.432 8.162 0 2.863-.479 5.584-1.432 8.161zM650.772 44.676h-15.606v100.23h15.606V44.676zM365.013 144.906h15.607V93.538h26.776V78.182h-42.383v66.724zM542.133 78.182l-19.616 51.096-19.616-51.096h-15.808l25.617 66.724h19.614l25.617-66.724h-15.808zM591.98 76.466c-19.112 0-34.239 15.706-34.239 35.079 0 21.416 14.641 35.079 36.239 35.079 12.088 0 19.806-4.622 29.234-14.688l-10.544-8.158c-.006.008-7.958 10.449-19.832 10.449-13.802 0-19.612-11.127-19.612-16.884h51.777c2.72-22.043-11.772-40.877-33.023-40.877zm-18.713 29.28c.12-1.284 1.917-16.884 18.589-16.884 16.671 0 18.697 15.598 18.813 16.884h-37.402zM184.068 43.892c-.024-.088-.073-.165-.104-.25-.058-.157-.108-.316-.191-.46-.056-.097-.137-.176-.203-.265-.087-.117-.161-.242-.265-.345-.085-.086-.194-.148-.29-.223-.109-.085-.206-.182-.327-.252l-.002-.001-.002-.002-35.648-20.524a2.971 2.971 0 00-2.964 0l-35.647 20.522-.002.002-.002.001c-.121.07-.219.167-.327.252-.096.075-.205.138-.29.223-.103.103-.178.228-.265.345-.066.089-.147.169-.203.265-.083.144-.133.304-.191.46-.031.085-.08.162-.104.25-.067.249-.103.51-.103.776v38.979l-29.706 17.103V24.493a3 3 0 00-.103-.776c-.024-.088-.073-.165-.104-.25-.058-.157-.108-.316-.191-.46-.056-.097-.137-.176-.203-.265-.087-.117-.161-.242-.265-.345-.085-.086-.194-.148-.29-.223-.109-.085-.206-.182-.327-.252l-.002-.001-.002-.002L40.098 1.396a2.971 2.971 0 00-2.964 0L1.487 21.919l-.002.002-.002.001c-.121.07-.219.167-.327.252-.096.075-.205.138-.29.223-.103.103-.178.228-.265.345-.066.089-.147.169-.203.265-.083.144-.133.304-.191.46-.031.085-.08.162-.104.25-.067.249-.103.51-.103.776v122.09c0 1.063.568 2.044 1.489 2.575l71.293 41.045c.156.089.324.143.49.202.078.028.15.074.23.095a2.98 2.98 0 001.524 0c.069-.018.132-.059.2-.083.176-.061.354-.119.519-.214l71.293-41.045a2.971 2.971 0 001.489-2.575v-38.979l34.158-19.666a2.971 2.971 0 001.489-2.575V44.666a3.075 3.075 0 00-.106-.774zM74.255 143.167l-29.648-16.779 31.136-17.926.001-.001 34.164-19.669 29.674 17.084-21.772 12.428-43.555 24.863zm68.329-76.259v33.841l-12.475-7.182-17.231-9.92V49.806l12.475 7.182 17.231 9.92zm2.97-39.335l29.693 17.095-29.693 17.095-29.693-17.095 29.693-17.095zM54.06 114.089l-12.475 7.182V46.733l17.231-9.92 12.475-7.182v74.537l-17.231 9.921zM38.614 7.398l29.693 17.095-29.693 17.095L8.921 24.493 38.614 7.398zM5.938 29.632l12.475 7.182 17.231 9.92v79.676l.001.005-.001.006c0 .114.032.221.045.333.017.146.021.294.059.434l.002.007c.032.117.094.222.14.334.051.124.088.255.156.371a.036.036 0 00.004.009c.061.105.149.191.222.288.081.105.149.22.244.314l.008.01c.084.083.19.142.284.215.106.083.202.178.32.247l.013.005.011.008 34.139 19.321v34.175L5.939 144.867V29.632h-.001zm136.646 115.235l-65.352 37.625V148.31l48.399-27.628 16.953-9.677v33.862zm35.646-61.22l-29.706 17.102V66.908l17.231-9.92 12.475-7.182v33.841z"
              />
            </g>
          </svg>
        </div>

        <div
          class="mt-8 overflow-hidden bg-white shadow  dark:bg-gray-800 sm:rounded-lg"
        >
          <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2">
            <div class="p-6">
              <div class="flex items-center">
                <svg
                  fill="none"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  stroke-linecap="round"
                  stroke-linejoin="round"
                  stroke-width="2"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  class="w-8 h-8 text-gray-500"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M12 6.253v13m0-13C10.832 5.477 9.246 5 7.5 5S4.168 5.477 3 6.253v13C4.168 18.477 5.754 18 7.5 18s3.332.477 4.5 1.253m0-13C13.168 5.477 14.754 5 16.5 5c1.747 0 3.332.477 4.5 1.253v13C19.832 18.477 18.247 18 16.5 18c-1.746 0-3.332.477-4.5 1.253"
                  ></path>
                </svg>
                <div class="ml-4 text-lg font-semibold leading-7">
                  <a
                    href="https://laravel.com/docs"
                    class="text-gray-900 underline dark:text-white"
                    >Documentation</a
                  >
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="ml-12">
                <div class="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400">
                  Laravel has wonderful, thorough documentation covering every
                  aspect of the framework. Whether you are new to the framework
                  or have previous experience with Laravel, we recommend reading
                  all of the documentation from beginning to end.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div
              class="p-6 border-t border-gray-200  dark:border-gray-700 md:border-t-0 md:border-l"
            >
              <div class="flex items-center">
                <svg
                  fill="none"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  stroke-linecap="round"
                  stroke-linejoin="round"
                  stroke-width="2"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  class="w-8 h-8 text-gray-500"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M3 9a2 2 0 012-2h.93a2 2 0 001.664-.89l.812-1.22A2 2 0 0110.07 4h3.86a2 2 0 011.664.89l.812 1.22A2 2 0 0018.07 7H19a2 2 0 012 2v9a2 2 0 01-2 2H5a2 2 0 01-2-2V9z"
                  ></path>
                  <path d="M15 13a3 3 0 11-6 0 3 3 0 016 0z"></path>
                </svg>
                <div class="ml-4 text-lg font-semibold leading-7">
                  <a
                    href="https://laracasts.com"
                    class="text-gray-900 underline dark:text-white"
                    >Laracasts</a
                  >
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="ml-12">
                <div class="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400">
                  Laracasts offers thousands of video tutorials on Laravel, PHP,
                  and JavaScript development. Check them out, see for yourself,
                  and massively level up your development skills in the process.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="p-6 border-t border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700">
              <div class="flex items-center">
                <svg
                  fill="none"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  stroke-linecap="round"
                  stroke-linejoin="round"
                  stroke-width="2"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  class="w-8 h-8 text-gray-500"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M7 8h10M7 12h4m1 8l-4-4H5a2 2 0 01-2-2V6a2 2 0 012-2h14a2 2 0 012 2v8a2 2 0 01-2 2h-3l-4 4z"
                  ></path>
                </svg>
                <div class="ml-4 text-lg font-semibold leading-7">
                  <a
                    href="https://laravel-news.com/"
                    class="text-gray-900 underline dark:text-white"
                    >Laravel News</a
                  >
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="ml-12">
                <div class="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400">
                  Laravel News is a community driven portal and newsletter
                  aggregating all of the latest and most important news in the
                  Laravel ecosystem, including new package releases and
                  tutorials.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div
              class="p-6 border-t border-gray-200  dark:border-gray-700 md:border-l"
            >
              <div class="flex items-center">
                <svg
                  fill="none"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  stroke-linecap="round"
                  stroke-linejoin="round"
                  stroke-width="2"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  class="w-8 h-8 text-gray-500"
                >
                  <path
                    d="M3.055 11H5a2 2 0 012 2v1a2 2 0 002 2 2 2 0 012 2v2.945M8 3.935V5.5A2.5 2.5 0 0010.5 8h.5a2 2 0 012 2 2 2 0 104 0 2 2 0 012-2h1.064M15 20.488V18a2 2 0 012-2h3.064M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"
                  ></path>
                </svg>
                <div
                  class="ml-4 text-lg font-semibold leading-7 text-gray-900  dark:text-white"
                >
                  Vibrant Ecosystem
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="ml-12">
                <div class="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400">
                  Laravel's robust library of first-party tools and libraries,
                  such as
                  <a href="https://forge.laravel.com" class="underline">Forge</a
                  >,
                  <a href="https://vapor.laravel.com" class="underline">Vapor</a
                  >,
                  <a href="https://nova.laravel.com" class="underline">Nova</a>,
                  and
                  <a href="https://envoyer.io" class="underline">Envoyer</a>
                  help you take your projects to the next level. Pair them with
                  powerful open source libraries like
                  <a href="https://laravel.com/docs/billing" class="underline"
                    >Cashier</a
                  >,
                  <a href="https://laravel.com/docs/dusk" class="underline"
                    >Dusk</a
                  >,
                  <a
                    href="https://laravel.com/docs/broadcasting"
                    class="underline"
                    >Echo</a
                  >,
                  <a href="https://laravel.com/docs/horizon" class="underline"
                    >Horizon</a
                  >,
                  <a href="https://laravel.com/docs/sanctum" class="underline"
                    >Sanctum</a
                  >,
                  <a href="https://laravel.com/docs/telescope" class="underline"
                    >Telescope</a
                  >, and more.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div
          class="flex justify-center mt-4 sm:items-center sm:justify-between"
        >
          <div class="text-sm text-center text-gray-500 sm:text-left">
            <div class="flex items-center">
              <svg
                fill="none"
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
                stroke-width="2"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                stroke="currentColor"
                class="w-5 h-5 -mt-px text-gray-400"
              >
                <path
                  d="M3 3h2l.4 2M7 13h10l4-8H5.4M7 13L5.4 5M7 13l-2.293 2.293c-.63.63-.184 1.707.707 1.707H17m0 0a2 2 0 100 4 2 2 0 000-4zm-8 2a2 2 0 11-4 0 2 2 0 014 0z"
                ></path>
              </svg>

              <a href="https://laravel.bigcartel.com" class="ml-1 underline">
                Shop
              </a>

              <svg
                fill="none"
                stroke="currentColor"
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
                stroke-width="2"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                class="w-5 h-5 ml-4 -mt-px text-gray-400"
              >
                <path
                  d="M4.318 6.318a4.5 4.5 0 000 6.364L12 20.364l7.682-7.682a4.5 4.5 0 00-6.364-6.364L12 7.636l-1.318-1.318a4.5 4.5 0 00-6.364 0z"
                ></path>
              </svg>

              <a
                href="https://github.com/sponsors/taylorotwell"
                class="ml-1 underline"
              >
                Sponsor
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div
            class="ml-4 text-sm text-center text-gray-500 sm:text-right sm:ml-0"
          >
            Laravel v{{ laravelVersion }} (PHP v{{ phpVersion }})
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.bg-gray-100 {
  background-color: #f7fafc;
  background-color: rgba(247, 250, 252, var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.border-gray-200 {
  border-color: #edf2f7;
  border-color: rgba(237, 242, 247, var(--tw-border-opacity));
}

.text-gray-400 {
  color: #cbd5e0;
  color: rgba(203, 213, 224, var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.text-gray-500 {
  color: #a0aec0;
  color: rgba(160, 174, 192, var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.text-gray-600 {
  color: #718096;
  color: rgba(113, 128, 150, var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.text-gray-700 {
  color: #4a5568;
  color: rgba(74, 85, 104, var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.text-gray-900 {
  color: #1a202c;
  color: rgba(26, 32, 44, var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .dark\:bg-gray-800 {
    background-color: #2d3748;
    background-color: rgba(45, 55, 72, var(--tw-bg-opacity));
  }

  .dark\:bg-gray-900 {
    background-color: #1a202c;
    background-color: rgba(26, 32, 44, var(--tw-bg-opacity));
  }

  .dark\:border-gray-700 {
    border-color: #4a5568;
    border-color: rgba(74, 85, 104, var(--tw-border-opacity));
  }

  .dark\:text-white {
    color: #fff;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, var(--tw-text-opacity));
  }

  .dark\:text-gray-400 {
    color: #cbd5e0;
    color: rgba(203, 213, 224, var(--tw-text-opacity));
  }
}
</style>

<script>
import { Head, Link } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
import ThemeToggler from "../Components/ThemeToggler.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    Head,
    Link,
    ThemeToggler,
  },
  props: {
    canLogin: Boolean,
    canRegister: Boolean,
    laravelVersion: String,
    phpVersion: String,
  },
  computed: {
    routeBasePath() {
      return this.$page.props.auth.routeBasePath;
    },
    isDark: function () {
      return this.$store.state.darkTheme;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I also had this inconvenience and this is how I solved it, without using "vuex"

1. Define the reactive variable "isDark", for this you have to import the dependencies

   ```
    import { reactive, computed, ref } from "vue";
    const isDark = ref();
   ```
2. Then I evaluate if it finds the dark mode in the local storage, if it exists I assign the value true to the isDark variable:

   ```
    isDark.value = localStorage.getItem("darkMode") == "true";
   ```
3. Then create a method to evaluate whether the value found in local storage is true or false

   ```
   function toggleDarkMode() {
        isDark.value = !isDark.value;
        localStorage.setItem("darkMode", isDark.value);
   }
   ```
4. Reference the class: If "isDark" is true then add the class "dark" . Ex:

   ```
   <body :class="{ dark: isDark }" class="flex flex-col h-screen bg-gray-100 dark: bg-gray-800">
   ```
5. Create a button or a switch and place the "toogleDarkMode()" function in the click method. Ex:

   ```
    <button @click="toggleDarkMode">Light|Dark :)</button>
   ```
6. Done!

Note: Don't forget to put darkMode: class in tailwind.config.js file

Reference: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode